# Inheriting a class with the same name in Python

Tags: python, class

I am new in Python and I am trying to create two classes with the same name in two different source files. Let’s call them "Main.py" and  "Extension.py". The class is "MyClass". MyClass in Extesntion.py is derived from MyClass in file *Main.py*. If it works then when I create an object myclass and I import Extension in my code, then I would have more functions in comparison with file *Main.py*.

#### File *Main.py*

```
    class MyClass:
       def __init__(self):
         Initialize something

       def foo1(self, a, b):
         Do something
```

Then extension would be like this:

#### File *Extensions.py*

```
    import Main

    class MyClass(MyClass):
       def __init__(self):
         Initialize something

       def foo2(self, a, b):
         Do something

       def foo3(self, a, b):
         Do something
```

And then if I have code like this. I expect that I can't use foo2 and foo3.

```
    import Main

    myclass = MyClass()
    myclass.foo1(a, b)
```

And finally if I have code like this. I expect that I use all the functions.

```
    import Extension

    myclass = MyClass()
    myclass.foo1(a, b)
    myclass.foo2(a, b)
    myclass.foo3(a, b)
```

Comment: Are you aware of `from {some.module} import {some_name}` form?

Comment: Yes but how it can do something I am searching for?

Comment: Well the others already beat me to the answer, but from import is the way to go here. Makes it rather easy for what you are asking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do

```
import main
```

you'll need to use `main.MyClass` to create an object from main.py.

Instead you can do

```
from main import MyClass
```

to have it available directly.

If you need two different classes with the same name, you can instead do

```
from main import MyClass as MainClass
```

and you'll have the class available under the name `MainClass`

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy when you explicitly import the given name using the `from {module} import {name}` syntax.

#### File *main.py*

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo1(self, a, b):
        pass
```

#### File *extensions.py*

```
from main import MyClass

class MyClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo2(self, a, b):
        pass

    def foo3(self, a, b):
        pass
```

#### File *client_main.py*

```
from main import MyClass

myinstance = MyClass()
myinstance.foo1(a, b)
```

#### File *client_extensions.py*

```
from extensions import MyClass

myinstance = MyClass()
myinstance.foo1(a, b)
myinstance.foo2(a, b)
myinstance.foo3(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do `from Extension import *`, you'll need to specify the module in order to access the class.

```
import Main
import Extension
foo = Main.MyClass()
bar = Extension.MyClass()
```

If you don't want to have to specify the module, then the only way to avoid a name collision is to import the class under a different name like so:

`from Main import MyClass as ClassA`

Answer (score 0):

Generally in this case, you would do an `import as`. This allows you to alias your import as a new name. So in the file where your second class is, import the first class as:

`from main import MyClass as MainMyClass`

Then when doing your inheritance, refer to `MainMyClass`:

`class MyClass(MainMyClass):`